# How to wire up modules and pass value

Tags: module, verilog, vivado

```
module container(x1, x2, x3, NUMBER);
input x1, x2, x3;
output NUMBER;
wire w0, w1;

dec_counter U1 (x1, x2, x3, w0, w1);
doz_counter U2 (w1, w0, NUMBER);
endmodule

module dec_counter(clk, reset, clk_enable, counter, terminal);
    input clk;
    input reset;
    input clk_enable;
    output reg [3:0] counter;
    output reg terminal;

    always @(posedge clk, posedge clk_enable, posedge reset)
        if(reset)
        begin
            terminal <= 1;
            counter <= 0;
        end
        else if(clk && clk_enable)
            if(counter < 9)
            begin
                terminal <= 1;
                counter <= counter + 1; 
            end           
            else
            begin
                terminal <= 1;
                counter <= 0;
            end  
endmodule

module doz_counter(dozens, unity, number);

input dozens;
input unity;
output reg [7:0] number;

initial begin
    number = 8'd0;
end    

always @(posedge dozens)
    if(dozens)
        number <= number + 1;

endmodule
```

I have module `dec_counter` which counts from 0 to 9. When it gets to 9+1, it shows 0 and set "output terminal" to 1. I wanted to pass that value to my next module `doz_counter` as "input dozens". I've tried wiring, as you can see in module container, but in my simulation, `dozens` is always X, even when `terminal` is 1.

I feel like I'm making some critical design mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted *works fine*. Refer the following figure for **port connection rules**. The output port can be any of `reg` or `wire`, but input port is always a `wire`.

[image: Port connection]

A **couple of mistakes** are listed as follows:

You have connected an **4-bit port**, `reg [3:0] counter;` in `dec_counter` module to **single bit port**, `w0` in `container` module. This shall result in port connection width mismatch.

```
wire [3:0] w0;
wire w1;
// ...
```

Similarly, **single bit port** `NUMBER` in `container` module is connected to **8-bit port** `number` in `doz_counter` module. This shall result in port connection width mismatch.

```
output [7:0] NUMBER;
//...
```

Also, the value of `terminal` upon **reset might be zero**. The `if`-`else` conditions are driving the same value of `terminal`. It should have **different values** of `terminal` as `terminal <= 1` and `terminal <= 0;` respectively.

Here is a testbench for your code for reference:

```
module top();

bit x1, x2, x3;
bit [7:0] NUMBER;

container c(x1, x2, x3, NUMBER);

always #5 x1 = ~x1;

initial
begin
#6 x2 = 1;
#6 x2 = 0; x3 = 1;
#100 $finish;
end

endmodule
```